# Setting TabIndex on TextBox within ASP.NET Dynamically Generated Controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabindex, composite-controls

I have a CompositeControl that each contain a TextBox (`TextBoxA`) and three Buttons (`ButtonA`, `ButtonB`, and `ButtonC`). My page generates *n* of these CompositeControls dynamically depending on the state of the page.

I've set the TabIndex of `TextBoxA` to a positive value that increases by 1 for each Control during that Control's OnPreRender method:

```
TextBoxA.TabIndex = customControlPosition;
ButtonA.TabIndex = -1;
ButtonB.TabIndex = -1;
ButtonC.TabIndex = -1;
```

I've validated through debugging that `customControlPosition` is correctly assigning positive, incremental values (1, 2, 3, 4 etc.) to the TabIndex property.

The current behavior is that each press of the `Tab` Key moves the cursor to highlight each of the Buttons within the CompositeControl (which have a TabIndex of -1, and shouldn't be tabbed to), before continuing to put the cursor in the next CompositeControl's TextBox.
What I want to do is have the `Tab` key move the focus **directly** from one TextBox to the TextBox in the next CompositeControl.

Is there something I'm missing that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.

The TextBox I was using is a custom class that was a wrapper of the asp:TextBox, and the custom class was not correctly assigning the TabIndex value to the asp:TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your buttons a `TabIndex` of 32767 (The maximum possible).  The higher the number, the later the control is in the tab order.

I would imagine 32767 is a lot higher than the number of controls you will ever add to a page?

See this:

[Tab Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried assigning the TabIndex of 32767 for each of the TextBoxes, and also also tried unique values of `(32700 + customControlPosition )` but have have the same behavior. The Tab Key moves to the Buttons within each control instead of the TextBox of the next Control.

Comment: The HTML output was not showing the tabindex value, which led me to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15503840/745511). Thank you!